# In which units did Sir Isaac Newton define force at that time as SI system didn't existed then?

Tags: mathematics, philosophy-of-science, newton

Sir Isaac Newton led the foundation of his famous laws of motion during the 17th Century but at that time SI system hadn't existed. So in which units did he define force? Did he define it in some other units or was later redefined by scientists who made the SI system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In which units did Sir Isaac Newton define force at that time as SI system didn't existed then?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13581/in-which-units-did-sir-isaac-newton-define-force-at-that-time-as-si-system-didn)

Answer (score 2):

The definitions related to Newton's laws of motion do not require the use of any units. The concepts of force, velocity, distance and time are expressed in general terms. Units are unnecessary.

Comment: And for that reason, all relations are stated as proportions instead of equalities.